# Group by fields in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following fields. For each Id, I have two records, that represent different latitude and longitudes. I'm trying to achieve a resultant dataframe that groups by current dataframe based on id and put its latitude and longitude into different fields.

I tried with the group by function but I do not get the intended results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Id  StartTime   StopTime    Latitude    Longitude
101 14:42:28    14:47:56    53.51       118.12
101 22:10:01    22:12:49    33.32       333.11
```

Result:

```
Id  StartLat    StartLong   DestLat DestLong
101 53.51       118.12      33.32       333.11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with apply function for return flatten `DataFrame` to `Series`:

```
df = df.groupby('Id')['Latitude','Longitude'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values.ravel()))
df.columns = ['StartLat', 'StartLong', 'DestLat', 'DestLong']
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
    Id  StartLat  StartLong  DestLat  DestLong
0  101     53.51     118.12    33.32    333.11
```

If problem:

> TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type

try change `Series` to `DataFrame`, but then need [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
df = df.groupby('Id')['Latitude','Longitude']
       .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values.ravel()))
       .unstack()
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
df.columns = ['StartLat', 'StartLong', 'DestLat', 'DestLong']
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
    Id  StartLat  StartLong  DestLat  DestLong
0  101     53.51     118.12    33.32    333.11
```

Comment: My dataframe has 400000 records. This group by works perfectly for 100 records. For more than 100 records itself, I get the error "TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type". Not sure why I get this error with increased number of records in the dataframe? Are these restricted by any specific size?

Comment: I have this problem also and solution is, give me a minute.